# Creating pivot tables and tables with relationships

Tags: excel, macos, statistics

I am doing my final year dissertation research and I just gathered all the results from my questionnaire, from which I got 210 responses.

I am really struggling with Excel here, so I hope somebody can help me with this.

I am running Mac Office 2011. I have a single file which is so composed:

```
                You are a... | You like... | Gender

participant 1   Carrot       | blu, red    | male
participant 2   Pear         | blu         | female
participant 3   Carrot       | red         | female
```

I was able to create a Pivot table of how "you are a...", like so:

```
Carrot   | 2
Pear     | 1
Total    | 3
```

I was also able to convert this total in percentage, by right clicking in the cell and selecting

```
Field settings > options > Show data as > % of total.
```

(by the way, there is a way to add another column with percentages next to the original numbers)

Anyway, my issues are the following:

1) how can I see ho many carrots and pears replied to the gender? Something like

```
          Male    | Female  | Total
Carrot    1       | 1       | 2
Pear      0       | 1       | 1
Total     1       | 2       | 3
```

2) Also, how many participants liked blue given that the field is single and contains all the values?

ps. all the data is already consistent as apart from a few fields, questions were multiple choice selection

Thank you very much for those who will help!

Comment: For 1) can you add Gender to the column area (similarly, you already have plants in the Row area). For 2) create a new PT or copy the old, replace plants with colors. Overloaded values like "blu, red" will not parse as "blu" -- you're on your own to separate those if it's important to count each color separately.

Comment: @andyholaday is right that you would need to separate items from your comma-separated list of colours before you create the pivot table - which is not trivial but is do-able. A partial solution, however, might be to create a pivot table with "You like" on the rows and then use the row `Label Filters > Contains = blu` to just pick out a specific value.